# Incorrect display of russian characters in redux state after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, utf-8, redux

What can be a reason for incorrect displaying of cyrillic chars in redux state AFTER page refresh? When string gets to state, it's ok, but after full page refresh I breaks. I set charset for script tag of my react app as well as for meta tags. Any suggestions?

Display is something like this : ÐÑÑÐ°ÑÐ¾Ðº

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect display?

Comment: @VijayaraghavanPurush, updated a post to show what I mean